# Are conversions from float* to float3* in CUDA safe?

Tags: c++, cuda, type-conversion, type-safety

I have just started diving into CUDA code, and its a bit of a blast from the past, lots of pointer access and type conversions through pointers using `reinterpret_cast`. I have a specific case that I wanted to check on, I have seen the following instance of type punning in the code:

```
__device__ void func(__restrict__ float* const points, size_t size, __restrict__ float* outputPoints) {

    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index += 3) {
        float3* const point = reinterpret_cast<float3* const>(points + index);
        float3* const output = reinterpret_cast<float3* const>(outputPoints + index);
        // operations using point;
    }
}
```

In CUDA you are provided a struct `float3` which looks like:

```
struct float3 {
    float x, y, z
}
```

Is this behaviour guaranteed to be safe? This is obviously some type punning, but I am pretty worried that there might be some padding or alignment or something that will ruin access in this way. If someone is able to give further insight on how the cuda compiler will deal with this, because I know that it does some very heavy optimizations as well. Can these cause problems?

Comment: I think what you are referring to is https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-increase-performance-with-vectorized-memory-access/ ?? This is quite old, and I am not sure that it is necessary anymore, since the optimizer seem to have improved quite a lot. Also I want to mention https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers for doing the host part of your cuda code in a modern c++ style.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy, yeah, time to start converting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA guarantees that the size of those built-in types will be consistent between host and device without padding interventions (no such guarantees exist for user defined structures and classes).

There are basic requirements for alignment on the device, such that the storage you read must be aligned to the size of the read. So you couldn't read a `float3` from an arbitrary byte boundary, but you will be safe reading from a 32 bit aligned boundary, and the memory allocation APIs which CUDA exposes on the host and device guarantee the necessary alignment to make the code you posted is safe.

The code you have posted (when modified to defeat dead code removal), basically just emits three 32 bit loads and three 32 bit stores. CUDA only has a limited number of native transaction sizes, and they don't map to a 96 bit per thread request, so there is absolutely no optimization by doing this:

```
__device__ void func(float* const points, size_t size, float* outputPoints) {

    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index += 3) {
        float3* point = reinterpret_cast<float3*>(points + index);
        float3* output = reinterpret_cast<float3*>(outputPoints + index);

    float3 val = *point;
    val.x += 1.f; val.y += 2.f; val.z += 3.f;
    *output = val;
    }
}
```

which does this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_75 -std=c++11 -dc -ptx fffloat3.cu 
$ tail -40 fffloat3.ptx 
    // .globl   _Z4funcPfmS_
.visible .func _Z4funcPfmS_(
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_0,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_1,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_2
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<3>;
    .reg .f32   %f<7>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<14>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd11, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd8, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_1];
    ld.param.u64    %rd12, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_2];
    setp.eq.s64 %p1, %rd8, 0;
    mov.u64     %rd13, 0;
    @%p1 bra    BB6_2;

BB6_1:
    ld.f32  %f1, [%rd11];
    ld.f32  %f2, [%rd11+4];
    ld.f32  %f3, [%rd11+8];
    add.f32     %f4, %f1, 0f3F800000;
    add.f32     %f5, %f2, 0f40000000;
    add.f32     %f6, %f3, 0f40400000;
    st.f32  [%rd12], %f4;
    st.f32  [%rd12+4], %f5;
    st.f32  [%rd12+8], %f6;
    add.s64     %rd12, %rd12, 12;
    add.s64     %rd11, %rd11, 12;
    add.s64     %rd13, %rd13, 3;
    setp.lt.u64 %p2, %rd13, %rd8;
    @%p2 bra    BB6_1;

BB6_2:
    ret;
}
```

i.e. all that casting is both syntactically bogus and pointless.

If you were to change to `float2`, which is a 64 bit request per thread and can be vectorized, so get this:

```
.visible .func _Z4funcPfmS_(
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_0,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_1,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_2
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<3>;
    .reg .f32   %f<7>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<14>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd12, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd8, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_1];
    ld.param.u64    %rd11, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_2];
    setp.eq.s64 %p1, %rd8, 0;
    mov.u64     %rd13, 0;
    @%p1 bra    BB6_2;

BB6_1:
    ld.v2.f32   {%f1, %f2}, [%rd12];
    add.f32     %f5, %f2, 0f40000000;
    add.f32     %f6, %f1, 0f3F800000;
    st.v2.f32   [%rd11], {%f6, %f5};
    add.s64     %rd12, %rd12, 8;
    add.s64     %rd11, %rd11, 8;
    add.s64     %rd13, %rd13, 2;
    setp.lt.u64 %p2, %rd13, %rd8;
    @%p2 bra    BB6_1;

BB6_2:
    ret;
}
```

Note that the loads and stores are now using a vectorized version of the instructions. Same with `float4`:

```
    // .globl   _Z4funcPfmS_
.visible .func _Z4funcPfmS_(
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_0,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_1,
    .param .b64 _Z4funcPfmS__param_2
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<3>;
    .reg .f32   %f<12>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<14>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd12, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd8, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_1];
    ld.param.u64    %rd11, [_Z4funcPfmS__param_2];
    setp.eq.s64 %p1, %rd8, 0;
    mov.u64     %rd13, 0;
    @%p1 bra    BB6_2;

BB6_1:
    ld.v4.f32   {%f1, %f2, %f3, %f4}, [%rd12];
    add.f32     %f9, %f3, 0f40400000;
    add.f32     %f10, %f2, 0f40000000;
    add.f32     %f11, %f1, 0f3F800000;
    st.v4.f32   [%rd11], {%f11, %f10, %f9, %f4};
    add.s64     %rd12, %rd12, 8;
    add.s64     %rd11, %rd11, 8;
    add.s64     %rd13, %rd13, 2;
    setp.lt.u64 %p2, %rd13, %rd8;
    @%p2 bra    BB6_1;

BB6_2:
    ret;
}
```

TLDR: Your concerns are valid, but the APIs and the compilers will handle sensible cases sensibly, but there are alignment and hardware limitations you should be extremely familiar with before trying to write "optimal code", because it is possible to write a lot of pointless nonsense unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, so CUDA guarantees alignment on the 32 bit boundary and no padding for this struct. The `cudaMalloc` that makes this memory also guarantees this, so we should be good.

Comment: I mean "does nothing" for the compiler, like any syntactic sugar, but it is nicer for a human to read.

Comment: Yes, but most people who write GPU code are focussed on performance, and most inexperienced beginners are a lot less wise than the compiler and will try all sorts of crazy stuff which is pointless. The rule should be -- just write code naturally and let the compiler do its magic. Then study its output and think whether your case could benefit from informed optmizations. Personally `float3 point(points[i], points[i+1], points[i+2]);` is much easier to read and understand than the code in your question, but that is just me.

Comment: Did you use Godbolt to do this assembly analysis?

Comment: No, I just used a local toolchain. AFAIK Godbolt doesn't let you look at the intermediate assembler (PTX which is what is in my answer). For proper performance analysis, what Godbolt shows is superior, but if you want to understand the compiler idioms at play, I prefer to look at PTX, There is still a chance that some of those PTX instructions don't have machine code equivalent and get replaced by pre-canned code stanzas